# How to get row-fluid to center properly?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a main row-fluid that is wrapping my entire scaffold that is made up of other spans and containers. However, I noticed that it's not centering properly.  I don't want to change the size of the middle span6 (in fact it could be a different size down the road) and I don't want to use left padding or margin offsets because it won't allow the page flush left on resize.

How can I get it to center properly.

Fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/GwCkp/19/show/

Basic scaffold is:

```
<div class="container"style="width: 1300px" >  // <- need this fixed size for spacing
  <div class="row-fluid">  // <-- row fluid that I need centered!
     <div class="span2">
     ...
     </>
     <div class="span6">
       <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="hero-unit">
          ...
          </>
          <div class="row-fluid">
          ...
          </>
       </>
     <div class="span2">
     ...
     </>
  </div><!-- end row-fluid -->
</div><!-- end container -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since twitter bootstrap has a 12 column grid you need actually to provide 12 columns to have it automatically centered. So the solution is simple, just add the two columns missing and everything gets centered nicely.

Basically this should be your layout, notice before the first `span2` and after the last I've added `<div class="span1"></div>`:

```
<div class="container"style="width: 1300px" >  // <- need this fixed size for spacing
  <div class="row-fluid">  // <-- row fluid that I need centered!
    <div class="span1"></div>
    <div class="span2">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="span2">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="span1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GwCkp/20/show/).

Comment: QQ, per http://jsfiddle.net/GwCkp/20/show/ how can I get the padding off the right and left sides so that resize will flush left with the page instead of padding on the left?